# Check if JSONObject matches JSON boolean expression

Tags: java, json, validation, optimization

To explain correctly the problem I must start with an example let's say I have a list of users like this

```json
[
    { "name": "John",  "surname": "Doe",   "age": 22 },
    { "name": "Syrus", "surname": "Black", "age": 20 }
]
```

And I have also a `JSONObject` representing a condition that must be matched like this:

```json
{
    "OR":[
        { "name": { "eq": "John"} },
        { "AND":[
            { "name": { "eq": "Syrus"} },
            { "age": { "gt": 18 } }
        ] }
    ]
}
```

Which should be translated in:

```
name = "John" OR (name = "Syrus" AND age > 18)
```

Now I have to make the code that given the `JSONObject` condition and the list of the users checks for each users if the condition is matched.
At the moment this is what I have done:

```java
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.TreeMap;
import java.util.function.BiConsumer;
import com.query.Queryable;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONObject;

public class QueryableTreeMap<K,V extends JSONObject> extends TreeMap<K,V> implements Queryable<JSONObject,JSONObject> {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 2586026774025401270L;

    private static boolean test(Set<Map.Entry<String, Object>> condition, JSONObject value){
        boolean isValid = true;
        Iterator<Map.Entry<String, Object>> iter = condition.iterator();
        while(iter.hasNext()){
            Map.Entry<String, Object> subcond = iter.next();
            if(subcond.getKey().equals("OR")){
                //isValid = isValid || test((Set<Map.Entry<String, Object>>) subcond.getValue(), value);
            } else if(subcond.getKey().equals("AND")){
                //isValid = isValid && test((Set<Map.Entry<String, Object>>) subcond.getValue(), value);
            } else if(subcond.getKey().equals("NOT")){
            
            } else {
                
            }
        }
        return isValid;
    }

    @Override
    public JSONObject query(JSONObject query) {
        // the set containing the conditions
        Set<Map.Entry<String, Object>> entries = query.toMap().entrySet();
        // the JSONArray with containing the records that match the condition
        JSONArray array = new JSONArray();
        // for each JSONObject inside this structure
        this.forEach(new BiConsumer<K,JSONObject>(){

            @Override
            public void accept(K key, JSONObject value) {
                // testing if the current record matches the condition
                if(test(entries, value)) array.put(value);
            }
            
        });
        // returns a JSONObject containing a JSONArray that contains the records that match the condition
        return new JSONObject(array);
    }
}
```

I am currently stuck in the test method which should in-fact test if the given object matches the given condition.

I don't mind changing the format of the JSON condition as long as it is a `JSONObject`.

At the moment i have come up with a partial solution that builds an object called Condition that represents the boolean expression inside the JSONObject (not very efficient but still a possible solution) this is obviously not working at the moment, i need help on what i should do now

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;

public class Condition {

    private Condition left, right;
    private String boolExpr, key, value;
    private boolean not;
    private int operationType; // greater then, less then, equal to, greater or equal of, less or equal of

    public Condition(Map<String, Object> map) {
        Set<Map.Entry<String, Object>> set = map.entrySet();
        Iterator<Map.Entry<String, Object>> iterator = set.iterator();
        while(iterator.hasNext()){
            Object entry = iterator.next();
            System.out.println(entry);
            System.out.println(entry.getClass());
            if(entry instanceof Map.Entry) {
                String key = (String) ((Map.Entry) entry).getKey();
                switch(key){
                    case "AND":
                    case "OR":
                        this.boolExpr = key;
                        break;
                    case "eq":
                    case "gt":
                    case "lt":
                    case "gte":
                    case "lte":
                        this.operationType = getOperationTypeFromString(key);
                        break;
                    case "NOT":
                        this.not = true;
                        break;
                    default:
                        this.key = key;
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public int getOperationTypeFromString(String operation) {
        switch(operation){
            case "eq":
                return 0;
            case "gt":
                return 1;
            case "lt":
                return 2;
            case "gte":
                return 3;
            case "lte":
                return 4;
            default:
                return 0;
        }
    }

}
```

I would prefer not to use the Condition class and just use the JSONObject instead.
I am using the org.json [JSON-Java](https://github.com/stleary/JSON-java) parser.

Comment: You mean `name == "John"`, not `name = "John"`? Also, you have "john" in your data instead of "John". Not sure if this is intentional.

Comment: Yes i am sorry i meant name == "John" and no it was not intentional the second error my bad!

Comment: OK, you could fix the data so that other's do not get confused.

Comment: I would use a recursive approach to evaluate the expression.

Comment: @Henry i am doing it but i am having troubles using Map, Set and Map.Entry to many datasturctures to handle, i am going to post what i have achieved. This problem really should be easy as a DFS in a tree, but it gets too much complicated with the amount of different datastuctures and cases to handle.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Edit: code updated to use org.json.

Below is a working implementation that handles your example.

The function that actually does the work is `match`, which recursively traverses the filter and applies each node to the supplied object. The function returns true if the given object satisfies the given filter.

Conceptually the `match` function is mapping each construct in your filter language (`AND`, `OR`, `EQ`, `LT` etc) into its Java equivalent. E.g. `AND` maps to `Stream.allMatch`, `NOT` maps to the Java `!` operator, `EQ` maps to `Object.equals`, etc. I.e. `match` is defining the semantics for your filter language.

I hope the code is self-explanatory - let me know if anything is unclear.

```
import org.json.*;

import java.io.*;
import java.nio.file.*;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.*;

import static java.util.stream.Collectors.toList;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        final List<JSONObject> jsObjs =
                stream(readJsonArray("users.json"))
                        .map(JSONObject.class::cast)
                        .collect(toList());

        final JSONObject jsFilter = readJsonObject("filter.json");

        final List<JSONObject> matches = applyFilter(jsObjs, jsFilter);

        System.out.println(matches);
    }

    private static List<JSONObject> applyFilter(List<JSONObject> jsObjs, JSONObject jsFilter) {
        return jsObjs.stream()
                .filter(jsObj -> match(jsObj, jsFilter))
                .collect(toList());
    }

    private static boolean match(JSONObject jsObj, JSONObject jsFilter) {

        final String name = getSingleKey(jsFilter);
        final Object value = jsFilter.get(name);

        switch (name) {
            case "AND":
                return stream((JSONArray)value)
                        .map(JSONObject.class::cast)
                        .allMatch(jse -> match(jsObj, jse));
            case "OR":
                return stream((JSONArray)value)
                        .map(JSONObject.class::cast)
                        .anyMatch(jse -> match(jsObj, jse));
            case "NOT":
                return !match(jsObj, (JSONObject)((JSONArray)value).get(0));
            default:
                final JSONObject jsOp = (JSONObject)value;
                final String operator = getSingleKey(jsOp);
                final Object operand = jsOp.get(operator);
                switch (operator) {
                    case "eq": return jsObj.get(name).equals(operand);
                    case "lt": return (Integer)jsObj.get(name) < (Integer)operand;
                    case "gt": return (Integer)jsObj.get(name) > (Integer)operand;
                    default: throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unexpected operator: " + operator);
                }
        }
    }

    private static JSONObject readJsonObject(String fileName) throws IOException {
        try (Reader reader = Files.newBufferedReader(Paths.get(fileName))) {
            return new JSONObject(new JSONTokener(reader));
        }
    }

    private static JSONArray readJsonArray(String fileName) throws IOException {
        try (Reader reader = Files.newBufferedReader(Paths.get(fileName))) {
            return new JSONArray(new JSONTokener(reader));
        }
    }

    private static Stream<Object> stream(JSONArray jsa) {
        return StreamSupport.stream(jsa.spliterator(), false);
    }

    private static String getSingleKey(JSONObject jso) {
        if (jso.length() != 1) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Expected single entry");
        } else {
            return jso.keySet().iterator().next();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I fully understand the code and let me compliment you this is a solid solution, the problem is that it would require me to change entirely the library i am using, which is not possible, however i will still upvote this in case someone in the future has the same problem.

Comment: It might help us find you a solution if you can state the problem more clearly. What library are you using and why does it prevent you from using the approach outlined above?

Comment: at the end of the question i have added the library i am using (org.json), i cannot implement the same algorithm with that library unfotunately.

Comment: I've changed the code to use the org.json library you're using. The same algorithm still works.